# How to invert the background of square headers from black to white in an image using python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to make the background of the square headers (The black bar that contains TERMS PONUMBER PROJECT) white and the text within black.

[image: sample_image of invoice]

I have tried using the findContours method to find the contours and then crop and invert them so that I get them in the black text and white background form. But the problem is I am not having any idea on how to proceed ahead or is there any better approach to this

```
image =cv2.imread("default.jpg")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElemnt(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
morp_image = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

contours = cv2.findContours(morp_image, 
cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnts = sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]
```

The code above does find each such contour on an individual basis like if I change the [-1] in the last line of the code to [-2], it will find the next contour but I want to find all such areas in the image in a single go and make the background of such areas white while changing the text to black.

Thanks

Comment: If any of the info on that sheet is PII I'd recommend redacting it and reposting the image.

Comment: You could also try to use `tesseract-ocr` to pull out the regions of text that you want and change the neighboring pixel values accordingly. Another approach would be to isolate the headers using `Hough Lines` in the horizontal direction and finding pairs of lines that are close to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Otsu's threshold to obtain binary image
- Find contours
- Filter using the number of corners and contour area
- Extract ROI, invert ROI, and replace into original image

---

The idea is that if the contour has 4 corners, it must be a square/rectangle. In addition, we filter using a minimum contour area to ignore noise. If the contour passes our filter then we have a desired ROI to invert. The detected ROIs

[image]

Now we extract each ROI using Numpy slicing. Here's each ROI before and after inverting

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Now we simply replace each inverted ROI back into the original image to get our result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = ROI

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: That was an amazing explanation !! Thank you so much @nathancy It solved my problem.

Comment: in cases where the square headers have a white background, this algorithm will make them black, which is not the purpose. It should not invert the headers with a white background.  How can we do that? @nathancy

Comment: One way is to check the ROI to determine the majority pixel color using `cv2.countNonZero()`. This function will check how many white pixels are on the grayscale image. If the majority of pixels is black then invert, if its white then don't do anything